# Use window functions to select the value from a column based on the sum of another column, in an aggregate query

Tags: sql, postgresql

Consider this data ([View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/q5jCqvdgyzqZFt8JZRyG8j/2)):

| id | dept | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 5 |
| 1 | A | 5 |
| 1 | B | 7 |
| 1 | C | 5 |
| 2 | A | 5 |
| 2 | A | 5 |
| 2 | B | 15 |
| 2 | A | 2 |

The base query I am running is pretty simple. Just get the total value by id and the most frequent dept.

```
SELECT 
  id,
  MODE() WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY dept) AS dept_freq,
  SUM(value) AS value
FROM test
GROUP BY id
;
```

| id | dept_freq | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 22 |
| 2 | A | 27 |

But I also need to get, for each id, the dept that concentrates the greatest value (so the greatest sum of value by id and dept, not the highest individual value in the original table).

Is there any way to use window functions to achieve that and do it directly in the base query above?

The expected output for this particular example would be:

| id | dept_freq | dept_value | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | A | 22 |
| 2 | A | B | 27 |

I could achieve that with the query below and then joining that with the results of the base query above

```
SELECT * FROM(
  SELECT 
    *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY value DESC) as row
  FROM (
    SELECT id, dept, SUM(value) AS value
    FROM test
    GROUP BY id, dept
  ) AS alias1
) AS alias2
WHERE alias2.row = 1
;
```

| id | dept | value | row |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 10 | 1 |
| 2 | B | 15 | 1 |

But it is not easy to read/maintain and seems also pretty inefficient. So I thought it should be possible to achieve this using window functions directly in the base query, and that also may also help Postgres to come up with a better query plan that does less passes over the data. But none of my attempts using over partition and filter worked.

Answer (score 1):

[step-by-step demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_15&fiddle=c7883ade83d7602abe33800881254fa8)

You can fetch the dept for the highest values using the `first_value()` partition function. Adding this before your `mode()` grouping should do it:

```
SELECT
    id,
    highest_value_dept,
    MODE() WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY dept) AS dept_freq,
    SUM(value) as value
FROM (
    SELECT
        id,
        dept,
        value,
        FIRST_VALUE(dept) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY value DESC) as highest_value_dept
    FROM test
) s
GROUP BY 1,2
```

Comment: thx @S-Man this helps!. Yet, the query does not return the expected output, because it fetches the first_value over ids. What I need is the first value, but considering the sum(value) over id and dept. Which would lead me, again, to aggregate at that level in other query because afaik you cannot use aggregate fns within window fns. I'll try to edit the question to make this more clear and include in the example the case where this particular query would not work

Comment: OK, why not another subquery? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_15&fiddle=70661511a3c9dda567d5165d6b13d0c6

Comment: yeah, that'll do. I was trying to avoid subqueries to try and keep it readable. I have to do this for a bunch of different columns, and using subqueries, it could easily result in a huge sql that is not easy to understand. Currently I do something like that, but using views or CTEs to try and keep the query readable. But I was hoping to find a way as elegant and concise as it works for the most frequent dept. For that, it's a one-liner `MODE() WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY dept) AS dept_freq` for a relatively similar data processing (albeit simpler).

Comment: Of course, you could put the subquery into a CTE. AFAIK in most cases a subquery may be more performant than a CTE.